# Downloading files from Ubuntu 1 to mac

Tags: ubuntu-one, downloads, macbook

I have tried to download my files from Ubuntu-one to my macbook but it doesn't work. 
I downloaded the u1-Downloader and called up directions for use on mac.

Below is what comes up in my terminal when I do everything according to directions:

```
Last login: Sat Jul 19 18:32:47 on ttys000    
macbooks-MacBook-Pro:~ macbook$ /Users/macbook/Downloads/u1-downloader-osx-r23/u1_downloader ; exit;    
U1 email: winjamarielutz@googlemail.com    
U1 password:     
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "<string>", line 374, in <module>    
  File "<string>", line 346, in main    
  File "<string>", line 152, in get_session    
  File "<string>", line 131, in _get_token    
  File "/Users/alecu/canonical/u1-downloader/build/u1_downloader/out00-PYZ.pyz/requests.api", line 88, in post    
  File "/Users/alecu/canonical/u1-downloader/build/u1_downloader/out00-PYZ.pyz/requests.api", line 44, in request    
  File "/Users/alecu/canonical/u1-downloader/build/u1_downloader/out00-PYZ.pyz/requests.sessions", line 383, in request    
  File "/Users/alecu/canonical/u1-downloader/build/u1_downloader/out00-PYZ.pyz/requests.sessions", line 486, in send    
  File "/Users/alecu/canonical/u1-downloader/build/u1_downloader/out00-PYZ.pyz/requests.adapters", line 385, in send    
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:343: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib    
logout

[Prozess beendet]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue My fix:

- Rename the downloaded and unzipped folder to u1_downloader
- Create a directory called /Users/alecu/canonical
- chown the alecu directory: chown -R username:group /Users/alecu
- mv the u1_downloader to /Users/alecu/canonical
- cd into the u1_downloader directory
- execute the following commmand ./u1_downloader